# Twitter API - Keyword search with nested list comprehension

Tags: search, list-comprehension, twitterapi-python, keyword-search

I would like to search the text of tweets.
With one keyword it works well. Several are a bit annoying: the code gets long when I use or:

`userTweets = [tweet for tweet in userTweets if 'OECD' in tweet['test'] or 'Abstimmung' in tweet['test']]` 
I could just go on and add as much or as I have additional keywords.

Instead I tried with a nested list comprehension to shorten the code

`keywords = ['Abstimmung', 'Steuern','OECD'] userTweets = [[x for x in keywords if x in tweet] for tweet in userTweets]`

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I get this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\nmr\Dropbox\Backup\Pultordner 2022\Jobs\Ideas\voxhelvetia\Twitter\15März2023_list keywords.py", line 67, in <module> userTweets.sort(key=lambda x:x['public']['like_count'], reverse = True) File "C:\Users\nmr\Dropbox\Backup\Pultordner 2022\Jobs\Ideas\voxhelvetia\Twitter\15März2023_list keywords.py", line 67, in <lambda> userTweets.sort(key=lambda x:x['public']['like_count'], reverse = True) TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Somebody can help?

I tried list comprehension instead of boolean or.

Comment: I am confused. Do you want to get all of the tweets for getting if ( `test`  and (`OECD`  or  `Abstimmung`)):  or something else?

Comment: I would like to get all tweets that contain either 'Abstimmung', 'Steuern' or 'OECD'. I would to put a free amount of keywords to be searched for in the tweets in a list.

Comment: It means 'Abstimmung' or 'Steuern' or 'OECD' any word include one of them?

Comment: @Bench Vue Exactly. Any of these words. My code words when I use 'or' but the code gets very long. Therefore I thought I could 'collect' all these keywords in an easier way like in a variable. You get me?

Comment: I got it but unfortunately  I can't test keywords full-archive search with my [`Elevated`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-level) access level, I checked Tweet supports [`Boolean operators and grouping`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query) Can you try it by your-self?

Comment: @Bench Vue 

Maybe I clarify a bit my question.

Actually I solved the problem by this code line:
userTweets = [tweet for tweet in userTweets if 'OECD' in tweet['test'] or 'Abstimmung' in tweet['test'] or 'Unterschrift' in tweet['test']

It works but is awkward to handle. Instead I tried: 

keywords = ['Abstimmung', 'Steuern','OECD']
userTweets = [[x for x in keywords if x in tweet] for tweet in userTweets]

The above code unfortunately doesn't work. 
What do you mean by self-test-it. I don't see the link to access levels :-( 
For me it remains a coding not an access question.

Comment: It means [that link](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-level) shows a table. its title is `Twitter API access levels and versions`.  One of row title is `Access to full-archive search Tweets`. it available  to depend on user's access level. In case of Essential and Elevated can't use that feature. Your keyword search needs access level only can do the Academic Research access level. Unfortunate, mine is Elevated level. So "Can you try it by your self?" Do you have an `Academic Research access`? If you has it you can do it.

Comment: @BenchVue No, I don't have Academic Research access. Nevermind, it's not a big thing since it actually already works. Concerning the access levels: Did you see that from May on Twitter will make you pay 100$ per month for pulling tweets :-(

Comment: OK, good hear it works, I am supersize too. Free account can only create tweet. and Basic account still not allow `full-archive search`. I think most free developer leave Tweet.

Comment: @BenchVue So, I got it right: A code as you helped me to develop (get_all_tweets) won't be possible in the future for free?

Comment: I thinks so from that [link](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-level), only can do `only Tweet creation` by V2 API.